# Is there a clean URL for upgrading the CiviCRM database (WordPress)?

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, clean

Is there a clean URL equivalent of the database upgrade URL?
I can use
**example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fupgrade&reset=1**
but **example.org/civicrm/upgrade&reset=1** doesn't do anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK - you need another /civicrm in your url, but that loads the content on your front end pages - clean URLs as you present are mainly for front end no?

for example

https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Ftag&reset=1
becomes
https://example.org/civicrm/civicrm/tag/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, clean urls are for front end pages. I didn't read the documentation throroughly enough 